# LinkedIn callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I want to call a function after clicking the share button for linked in.

```
 <div class="linkedinShare ci-aling" linkedin data-url='{{url}}' data-title='{{title}}' data-summary="{{text}}" data-shares='linkedinshares'>{{linkedinshares}}</div>
```

Here is the script I am trying to call, but it only gets called on page load and doesn't get called on click of linked in share button. I want my fuction to be called when i click the share button.

```
$.getScript('http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js', function () {
    debugger
    IN.Event.on(IN, 'systemReady', handleLinkedInEvent);

    function handleLinkedInEvent(event) {
        debugger
        if (event) {
            EventService.UpdateEventAudit($scope.event_id, "LinkedIn", 
            GetUrlReferrer());
        }
    }
});
```

UpdateEventAudit is the function i am trying to call. Any idea anyone?

Comment: Where is the `click` event? Also, `data-shares` is missing interpolation brackets?

Comment: @Rafael this is supposed to be the click event IN.Event.on(IN, 'systemReady', handleLinkedInEvent);
you mean data-shares='linkedinshares' should be data-shares={{linkedinshares}} ??

Comment: @Rafael as far as i could know from R&d , ONCLICK of share button, the linkedin script gets called, and it then executes the event and the callback function defined in it, but don't know for what reason this isn't happening correctly

Comment: You'll need to register the event with `$('.linkedinShare').click()` or similar, [read here.](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: @Rafael $('.linkedinShare').click() is fired on page load and doesn't get called on click of button, i need a way to call it on click of share button

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. Is this LinkedIn script adding a share button to your page that you'd like to register click events to? If so,, we'd need to see the created element and the handler code you're describing.

Comment: @Rafael yes, do you need to see the dynamic elements created in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding this correctly, you want to be able to track events when a user shares via linkedin...

I did try your code and after some R&D, found an alternative way to call the api...

created a mini-pen which you can view here https://codepen.io/craigiswayne/pen/Bqqbjz

Documentation on this subject can be found here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

```js
IN.Event.on(IN, 'systemReady', function() {
    var shareLink = document.getElementById('shareLink');
    shareLink.onclick = function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      var params = {
        "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! " + this.getAttribute('href'),
        "visibility": {
          "code": "anyone"
        }
      };

      IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
      .method("POST")
      .body(JSON.stringify(params))
      .result(StackOverflowDemo.updateShareCount)
      .error(function(errorMessage){
        StackOverflowDemo.logOutput('error occurred');
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
    };

    document.body.appendChild(shareLink);

  });

  var StackOverflowDemo = {
    updateShareCount: function(result){
      var existingCount = parseInt( document.getElementById('count').value );
      existingCount = isNaN(existingCount) ? 0 : existingCount;
      document.getElementById('count').value =  existingCount + 1;
      StackOverflowDemo.logOutput( 'updated count' );
      StackOverflowDemo.logOutput( 'Total Shares = ' +  document.getElementById('count').value );
      StackOverflowDemo.logOutput( 'View Share here ' + result.updateUrl );
    },
    logOutput: function(text){
      document.getElementById('output').value +=  text + '\n';
    }
  }
```